# Adding namespaces to existing project

Tags: php, namespaces

I wrote a PHP project over years ago before PHP 5.3 added namespaces. Now I need to continue to work on it and I want to upgrade it to current PHP standards.

The project is already divided to directories that I want them to be the namespaces. So for upgrading, I need to add `namespace ...` line before each class definition, and change all the class usage, say from `new Foo()` to `new Bar\Foo()`.

The project is very complex and it very hard to do it manually. So what is the easy way to add namespaces to the project? Is there any automatic tools for that? (I don't care about autoloaders)

Comment: Why don't you care about auto-loaders? Simplest would be using namespace according to your directory structure/hierarchy naming and with the right IDE use refactoring and the 'use' statement (besides namespace) to prevent using namespace naming in front of class instantiation, e.g. 'use Foo/Bar' will let your instantiate 'new Bar()' without a hassle

Comment: @dbf Which IDE can refactoring the namespaces automatically? BTW, I changed the autoloader to `spl_autoload`. And it have native support of namespaces.